# Retrieving data with sqlite and flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'm working on a Flutter project and using Sqflite database. I've managed to save data in db and i am trying to show data saved in sqllite,i am trying with listview builder but it throws the error `The getter 'length' was called on null.`.but i am getting data from the database it have no problem

**Error**

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<CartModel>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<CartModel>>#31bfe):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

**Retrieving data from database to view**

```
  Widget Coupon_List() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<CartModel>>(
      future: productFromDatabase(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(snapshot.data[index].boon_name,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)),
                      new Divider()
                    ]);
              });
        } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return new Text("No Data found");
        }
        return new Container(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**Fetch database function to view**

```
Future<List<CartModel>> productFromDatabase() async {
    Future<List<CartModel>> product = dbHandler.getCartList();
    return product;
  }
```

**DbHelper class for Retrieving data**

```
  Future<List<CartModel>> getCartList() async {
    List<Map> list = await _db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Cart');
    List<CartModel> productList = new List();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var data=list[i];
      productList.add(CartModel.fromJson(data));
    }
    print(productList.length);
    return productList;
  }
```

This is data i am getting from db

```
[{id: 1, boon_id: 3, product_id: 15, boon_name: iPhone 11 Pro Max, product_name: Boon Polo Tshirt, product_price: ₹599.00, quantity: 0, product_size: M, product_color: Blck, product_image: https://www.boonways.com//images/gallery/1593989052.jpg, boon_image: https://www.boonways.com//images/coupon/coupon_15_20200706040643.jpg, percentage: 14.43}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this function

```
Future<List<CartModel>> productFromDatabase() async {
    Future<List<CartModel>> product = dbHandler.getCartList();
    return product;
  }
```

to

```
Future<List<CartModel>> productFromDatabase() async {
    List<CartModel> product = await dbHandler.getCartList();
    return product;
  }
```

and also change this

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(snapshot.data[index].boon_name,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)),
                      new Divider()
                    ]);
              });
        } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return new Text("No Data found");
        }
```

into

```
if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length > 0) {
          return new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(snapshot.data[index].boon_name,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)),
                      new Divider()
                    ]);
              });
        } else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return new Text("No Data found");
        }
```

Let me know what happened.

Comment: Now the error is gone but still not working i have added circularpageindicator in else part.so it shows the circularpageindicator nothing else.even though there is data in database @Tipu

Comment: hey man,any idea about this,still haven't figured it yet. @Tipu

Comment: @MorbiusBlack did you print the length of your list?

Comment: `[{id: 1, boon_id: 3, product_id: 15, boon_name: iPhone 11 Pro Max, product_name: Boon Polo Tshirt, product_price: ₹599.00, quantity: 0, product_size: M, product_color: Blck, product_image: https://www.boonways.com//images/gallery/1593989052.jpg, boon_image: https://www.boonways.com//images/coupon/coupon_15_20200706040643.jpg, percentage: 14.43}]` this what i am getting when i run this function `getCartList`  @Tipu

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems you are doing this inside your builder (pseudocode):

```
if there is data then do
   return widget
else if the data-length is equal to zero then do
   return widget
end if-else
```

Which could give you an error if no data is returned and `snapshot.data` is null (the `else if` part), which could explain this message:

> The getter 'length' was called on null.

But I'm not sure where the error occurs. You should probably change that condition and verify. Perhaps something like this:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    if(snapshot.data.length == 0) {
        return Text('No data');
    }
    return Text('Data is here');
} else if(snapshot.hasError){
    return Text('Something went wrong');
} else {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

Comment: Now the error is gone but still not working i have added circularpageindicator in else part.so it shows the circularpageindicator nothing else.even though there is data in database @user2352776